# Top percentage of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table with 3000 records.

```
PRODUCT
-----------
PID
QTY
EMPID
```

When I try to get 5% of records for each employee ID, It is returning 5% of total records instead of 5% for each employee.

```
SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT EMPID,QTY,PID FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY EMPID,QTY,PID
```

How do I get 5% of records for each employee rather than 5% of the total.

Appreciate if you can helo

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server might have a better way to do this, but one simple option using `COUNT` as analytic function would be:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY QTY DESC) /
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID) AS cnt_pct
    FROM PRODUCT
)

SELECT EMPID, QTY, PID
FROM cte
WHERE cnt_pct <= 0.05;
```

This return only records for each employee which corresponded to the top 5% as ordered descending by quantity.  Note that your original query probably should have some sort of `ORDER BY` clause, without which `TOP` does not make much sense.